# How to export/import Database

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sqlite

I have an app.js there I got this lines :

```
 const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
 let db = new sqlite3.Database("./DB/Datenbank.db");
```

How can I use this database in my main.js ? everytime I use db. I got the error "db" is not defined.

i exported like this : exports.db = db;
and imported like this: const db = require("../app.js")
but every time the page needs to use the db I got the error : db.get is not a function. So I think the export/import is not correct

Comment: export it then use it  when ever you want by importing it

Comment: ty `export default db` or `module.exports = db` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can export and import your db instance like so:

```
//db.js

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./DB/Datenbank.db");

module.exports = db
```

```
// index.js
const db = require('./db')

// using db const logic here...
```

Comment: got the same error : typeError: db.get is not a function